# What is causing the incorrect build directory structure after integrating a third-party library in my VueJS component library using Webpack 4?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, build, directory-structure, webpack-4

I'm integrating a third-party library into a shared VueJS component library, but upon doing so, our Webpack build directory changed from a folder structure of:

```
- dist
  - components
    - ComponentBase.vue.d.ts
    - index.d.ts
  - index.d.ts
  - index.js
```

To:

```
- dist
  - src
    - components
      - ComponentBase.vue.d.ts
      - index.d.ts
      - UsesComponent.vue.d.ts
    - index.d.ts
  - index.js
```

This then means our type declarations are in the incorrect location and other projects cannot correctly import the shared library.

We are using Webpack version 4.41.5 and this is our webpack.config.js:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/* eslint-disable object-curly-newline */
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  target: 'web',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] },
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: (file) => /node_modules/.test(file) && !/\.vue\.js/.test(file),
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: { importLoaders: 1 },
          },
          'postcss-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'component_library',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  externals: {
    'core-js': {
      commonjs: 'core-js',
      commonjs2: 'core-js',
      amd: 'core-js',
      root: '_',
    },
    moment: {
      commonjs: 'moment',
      commonjs2: 'moment',
      amd: 'moment',
      root: '_',
    },
    vue: { commonjs: 'vue', commonjs2: 'vue', amd: 'vue', root: '_' },
    'vue-class-component': {
      commonjs: 'vue-class-component',
      commonjs2: 'vue-class-component',
      amd: 'vue-class-component',
      root: '_',
    },
    'vue-property-decorator': {
      commonjs: 'vue-property-decorator',
      commonjs2: 'vue-property-decorator',
      amd: 'vue-property-decorator',
      root: '_',
    },
    'vue-router': {
      commonjs: 'vue-router',
      commonjs2: 'vue-router',
      amd: 'vue-router',
      root: '_',
    },
    vuex: { commonjs: 'vuex', commonjs2: 'vuex', amd: 'vuex', root: '_' },
    '@microsoft/signalr': {
      commonjs: '@microsoft/signalr',
      commonjs2: '@microsoft/signalr',
      amd: '@microsoft/signalr',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@tinymce/tinymce-vue': {
      commonjs: '@tinymce/tinymce-vue',
      commonjs2: '@tinymce/tinymce-vue',
      amd: '@tinymce/tinymce-vue',
      root: '_',
    },
    'v-tooltip': {
      commonjs: 'v-tooltip',
      commonjs2: 'v-tooltip',
      amd: 'v-tooltip',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@types/prismjs': {
      commonjs: '@types/prismjs',
      commonjs2: '@types/prismjs',
      amd: '@types/prismjs',
      root: '_',
    },
    prismjs: {
      commonjs: 'prismjs',
      commonjs2: 'prismjs',
      amd: 'prismjs',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-drawing': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-drawing',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-drawing',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-drawing',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-licensing': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-licensing',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-licensing',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-licensing',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-svg-icons': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-svg-icons',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-svg-icons',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-svg-icons',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-vue-animation': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-vue-animation',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-vue-animation',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-vue-animation',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-vue-buttons': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-vue-buttons',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-vue-buttons',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-vue-buttons',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-vue-common': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-vue-common',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-vue-common',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-vue-common',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-vue-dialogs': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-vue-dialogs',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-vue-dialogs',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-vue-dialogs',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-vue-dropdowns': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-vue-dropdowns',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-vue-dropdowns',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-vue-dropdowns',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-vue-editor': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-vue-editor',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-vue-editor',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-vue-editor',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-vue-form': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-vue-form',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-vue-form',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-vue-form',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-vue-inputs': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-vue-inputs',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-vue-inputs',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-vue-inputs',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-vue-intl': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-vue-intl',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-vue-intl',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-vue-intl',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-vue-layout': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-vue-layout',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-vue-layout',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-vue-layout',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-vue-pdf': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-vue-pdf',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-vue-pdf',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-vue-pdf',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-vue-popup': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-vue-popup',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-vue-popup',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-vue-popup',
      root: '_',
    },
    '@progress/kendo-vue-progressbars': {
      commonjs: '@progress/kendo-vue-progressbars',
      commonjs2: '@progress/kendo-vue-progressbars',
      amd: '@progress/kendo-vue-progressbars',
      root: '_',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    //new WebpackShellPlugin({onBuildEnd: ["pnpm run kendoTest"]}),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

As a work-around, I am running a shell command to reformat the output, but it seems unusual that I need to do this. Any advice on how to resolve the issue would be greatly appreciated.

I have created a sample application where the behaviour can be seen [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webpack-webpack-js-org-tfuvfv?file=README.md)